# Show a modal dialog after the success in a "IF-STATEMENT"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm trying to show a modal dialog after the result of a "if" statement, without a button which could open it, is it there any way to show it using only the response of the condition statement?

Currently I'm developing in Model View Controller. so when i make the call i do something like this in the controller:

```
if($response == "success"){
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#eventCreated').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
}
```

and the modal in the bottom of my view looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="eventCreated" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
     labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Great!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is test 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
         dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">create</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? What is the value of `$response`

Comment: from where you are getting `$response == "success"`

Comment: the value of response is "success" or "error", string chains.

Comment: and the value's response come from a SQL statement in my model to add data in my DB. So, what i whant is when the user add some data in the DB, the system automatically shows a modal telling it if the action was successful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this is helpful for you, after all its depends on response. I use response variable to show just demo

```js
var response = "success";
if (response == "success") {

  $('#eventCreated').modal('show');

}
$("button").click(function(){
var response = "success";
if (response == "success") {

  $('#eventCreated').modal('show');

}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="eventCreated">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Great!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is test 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">create</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well actually it works using :

 `if($response == "success"){
 <script> 
$(function() { $('#eventCreated').modal('show'); }); </script> } `


the problem is when i open the modal the page just get blocked instantly, i think is a problem with the MVC structure when i open my modal. –

Comment: might be sync operation is blocking. you can found where it get stuck in source console

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($response == "success"){
  <script>
    $('#eventCreated').modal('show');
  </script>
}
```

Otherwise, you have to print the value of $response.

Comment: PHP in jQuery or jQuery in PHP?

Comment: well actually it works using : 
                                                                                       
`if($response == "success"){
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#eventCreated').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
}`

the problem is when i open the modal the page just get blocked instantly, i think is a problem with the MVC structure when i open my modal.

Comment: @devpro Its actually jQuery inside PHP :-)

Comment: May be you have installed broken MVC

Comment: Or may be you have missing files or any cache issue.